# Fixed height in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, scrollbar

From the link at [davidwalsh](http://davidwalsh.name/cross-browser-css-min-height), it says that in IE6, the container expands vertically even when a hard set height is defined. So how do I define a max-height in IE6, so that until that height is achieved, the container should go on expanding with its content, but once that height is exceeded, scrollbars should appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has to be enabled, but this works for supporting IE6.

```
* html div#division { 
   height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 332 ? "333px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-height for IE */
}
div#division {
   max-height: 333px; /* sets max-height value for all standards-compliant browsers */
}
```

http://perishablepress.com/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Well, that looks like a heavy bug, doesn't it, without these kind of tweaks, is it not possible to make vertical scollbars appear on an element (of course it doesn't support max-height as well)?

Comment: Plus is there no way to achieve this without Javascript?

Comment: Yeah, for this case you'll need javascript enabled.  I would strongly suggest informing your users to upgrade their browser if they have IE6.  http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: For this case, of course. But is there no way to achieve this without Javascript, just CSS alone?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have IE6 to test, but if I remember correctly it would honor the height on a table and tr and td (if only all done together).